# Zk how to pass parameter from java code to zk page?

Tags: java, zk

I am novice in ZK.

I use very old zk framework version(legacy project).

I render zk page so:

```
Executions.createComponents("/myZul.zul", null, null))
```

I need to pass parameter to zul. And if parameter is true I need render checkbox and otherwise - not on `myZul.zul`

I need something like this on zul:

```
if(parameter){

    <checkbox id="my_id" label="my checkbox"  />
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
my zul:

```
<window xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:zk="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk"
        xmlns:ca="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul      http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd "
        border="normal"
        closable="false"
        position="center,center"
        width="383px"
        height="270px"
        onCancel="self.detach();"
        id="decisionCommentWindow"
        title="${c:l('approvalTaskWindow.title')}"
        use="handlers.ZulHandler">
        ....
```

I need override method `doAfterCompose` inside of ZulHandler?

**One more time:**

zul:

```
<window xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:zk="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk"
        xmlns:ca="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd "
        border="normal"
        closable="false"
        position="center,center"
        width="383px"
        height="270px"
        onCancel="self.detach();"
        id="decisionCommentWindow"
        title="${c:l('approvalTaskWindow.title')}"
        use="handlers.ZulHandler">


    <zk if="${isManufacturingKey}">

        <checkbox id="checkbox_id" label="check"  />

    </zk>






</window>
```

zul creater:

```
...
Map args = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                    Boolean isManufacturing = true;
                    args.put("isManufacturingKey", isManufacturing);
                    ZulHandler window = Preconditions
                            .checkNotNull((ZulHandler) Executions.createComponents(
                                    "/decision_comment_window.zul", null, args));
                    window.setTitle(decisionModel.getName() + " decision");
                    if (isManufacturing) {
                        Checkbox checkbox = (Checkbox) Path
                                .getComponent("/decisionCommentWindow/emergency_change_checkbox_id");
                        checkbox.setChecked(workflow.getEmergencyChange());//I have Null pointer here  because checkbox is null
                    }
...
```

Comment: post or get parameter?

Comment: What class do you implement or extend in zulhandlers?

Comment: doin't you have a controller or vm? what version of zk is it? (mine answer certainly working on 5.0 and higher, for before I have to check)

Comment: I just checked, GenericAutowireComposer exist from version 3.0.6
So I really recomend you implement an controller. (in window you will have apply="MyComposer" )

Comment: after window inheritance I override only *doOk* method

Answer (score -4, accepted):

java code:

```
Map args = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
args.put("isManufacturingKey", true);
ZulHandler window = Preconditions.checkNotNull((ZulHandler) Executions.createComponents("/decision_comment_window.zul", null, args));
```

right access in .zul file:

```
"${arg.isManufacturingKey}"
```

note: I access to parameter using *arg*  accessor

**It is working for my ZK version!!!**

Comment: Of course this works, but bad practice to ask arg in zul.
What will your output be if you don't pass the param because this you can use in other cases to?
Play sure and do it in your code.

Comment: at this case I don't see checkbox

Comment: I have this variable in zul creating place!

Comment: Indeed you couldn't see the checkbox, I had little fault in the zul.
Does that works now?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this :

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Boolean isManufacturing = true;
args.put("isManufacturingKey", isManufacturing);   
map.put("isManufactringChecked",workflow.getEmergencyChange());
Executions.createComponents("/myZul.zul", null , map);
```

create this controller :

```
public class ZulHandler extends SelectorComposer {

  @Wire("#win")
  private Window myWin;
  private Boolean manufacturing;
  private Boolean manufactringChecked; 
  @Override
  public void doAfterCompose(Component window) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(window);

    if (arg.containsKey("isManufacturingKey")) {
        manufacturing =  (Boolean) arg.get("isManufacturingKey"));
    } else {
       //Declare what is is when you don't have the arg
    }
    if (arg.containsKey("isManufactringChecked")) {
        manufactringChecked =  (Boolean) arg.get("isManufactringChecked"));
    } else {
       //Declare what is is when you don't have the arg
    }
}

public Boolean isManufacturing () {
    return manufacturing;
}

public Boolean isManufactringChecked() {
    return manufactringChecked ;
}
```

change your zul from this :

```
use="handlers.ZulHandler">
<zk if="${isManufacturingKey}">
    <checkbox id="checkbox_id" label="check" />
</zk>
```

to :

```
apply="handlers.ZulHandler">
<checkbox id="checkbox_id" label="check" checked="${$composer.manufactringChecked}"
    visible="${$composer.manufacturing}"/>
```

Now you just need to implement the doOk method there.
If its a button that just close that window you can do the following in the zul :

```
<button label="Close" onClick="spaceOwner.detach()" />
```

edit: 
Mine first solution was correct for your problem. You just have the next problem because you work wrong.
Your problem is that you want your caller to influence the target.
Just give params and let the controller of your target do the work.
It's like a car factory, they say your car can drive up to 200km/hr, but you as controller of the car, do you drive 200 km/hr or when its not specified, can you still drive the car? 
You also don't need to make dubbelposts for the same issue.  You could make an issue for the nullpointer but the title is almost the same and what's in the post also.

edit:

If you need to set the title => put the title in the args and claim in in your code.
otherwise, I edited the controller class so you have your window variable.(or you make yourself a public getter and setter for the window)

Comment: If you call super.doAfterCompose( comp ) from your doAfterCompose(...) in a GenericForwardComposer, the args variable is autowired for you. So, it will have all the values passed as the 3rd argument to Executions.createComponents(...).

Comment: I don't want get access from controller to username. I want get access from my .zul file.  Sorry for bad problem axplanation.

Comment: after change use to apply I have classCast Exception

Comment: MyWindow cannot be cast to
org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Composer

Comment: I have 3 things: 1. zul creator 2 .zul file 3 zul handler. I need create variable in zul creator and get variable in .zul file

Comment: you can rename the class to what you want. Just adjust the new name also to the zul. (if you mean the name already exist somewhere)

Comment: sorry. *ZulHandler extends org.zkoss.zul.Window* . In java I cannot extends more than 1 class

Comment: you don't have to extend window anymore, that's also not in mine answer ;)

Comment: new edit of answer (if you really want to acces window in the caller class make a public Window getWindow () in the controller (and see that I changed the extends)

Answer (score 0):

I created a zul and set arg in main zul. send a parameter and  I want to change this parameter.
For example:

```
Map args = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); 
args.put("ReadOnly", false);
Executions.createComponents("/example.zul", null, args);
```

if I save button cliked and changing ReadOnly true, How to change ReadOnly in main.zul;

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
<zk if="${parameter}">

<checkbox id="my_id" label="my checkbox"  />

</zk>
```

more info:http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advanced/Pass_Arguments_to_Include_Component

Comment: Where and how in java code  should I mention the *parameter* ?