# variable doesn't pass from java code to zul

Tags: java, zk

I try to pass parameter to zul when I create it:

.zul file:

```
<window xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:zk="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk"
        xmlns:ca="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd "
        border="normal"
        closable="false"
        position="center,center"
        width="383px"
        height="270px"
        onCancel="self.detach();"
        id="decisionCommentWindow"
        title="${c:l('approvalTaskWindow.title')}"
        use="handlers.ZulHandler">


    <zk if="${isManufacturingKey}">

        <checkbox id="checkbox_id" label="check"  />

    </zk>

</window>
```

java code, that create zul:

```
    ...
    Map args = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    Boolean isManufacturing = true;
    args.put("isManufacturingKey", isManufacturing);
    ZulHandler window = Preconditions
             .checkNotNull((ZulHandler) Executions.createComponents(
                            "/decision_comment_window.zul", null, args));
    window.setTitle(decisionModel.getName() + " decision");
    if (isManufacturing) {
           Checkbox checkbox = (Checkbox) Path
                        .getComponent("/decisionCommentWindow/emergency_change_checkbox_id");
           checkbox.setChecked(workflow.getEmergencyChange());//I have Null pointer here  because checkbox is null
    }
             ...
```

I have null pointer here.

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zk how to pass parameter from java code to zk page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024642/zk-how-to-pass-parameter-from-java-code-to-zk-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feel the differences:

**wrong variant**:

```
<zk if="${isManufacturingKey}">
```

**right variant**:

```
<zk if="${arg.isManufacturingKey}">
```

maybe cause of this problem is the old version of using zk framework - I don't know.

Comment: If you intended to make a correction on your original question, you should edit your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Is current answer enough complete?